# Why is my mac replacing my name on all my email as "Holiday In The United States"?

Tags: mac, mail.app, email, gmail, smtp

Recently I noticed that on both [Spark](https://sparkmailapp.com/) and the default mail app, my name is being replaced as "Holiday In The United States". This is happening on all my accounts, with various email providers. I have verified my name in both System Preferences, Spark Preferences, and Mail Preferences. Additionally, I have checked my name on each email provider's settings. To clarify, I am only seeing my name as "Holiday In The United States" from my Mac, not online.

Any way I can fix this? It is really annoying having to log-in from the browser to send mail.

I am currently on a MacBook Pro Mid 2014, running Mac OS Sierra 10.12.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good thing is that you haven't got a virus, or been hacked. The bad thing is this has been a *bug* (for want of a better word) that seems to appear from time to time and it's been around for way too long!

There is no single catch-all solution that works in all cases, so it's not so easy to provide a quick answer here. However, you may find the following online discussions useful:

- [My gmail name comes up as Holidays in the United States](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/qvAg3NmPpSs)
- [Why does my name say Holidays In United States](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6672959?tstart=0)
- [Mail changes my name to some odd contact or calendar group](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6654319?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Wow, you would figure Apple would have figured something out in 3 years.

Comment: Agreed. :( All I can think of is that there must be some unusual combination of factors that result in this behaviour and they either haven't been able to determine what they are, __or__ there's more than one combination of factors and they haven't all been identified yet. Not excusing them - I just know how hard it can be to identify what's causing something when it only happens to a relatively small number of users and is therefore hard to replicate in testing. :(

Answer (score 0):

This has bothered me for years and I just fixed it.
I went to https://contacts.google.com/search/holidays and there was the rogue contact entry. I deleted it and voila no more problems. You may however be better served just editing it. (After deleting it gmail would not autocomplete my email address so I had to go into another contact entry and make further changes - it may have been easier to just edit it in the first place.)

Appreciate this is another holy thread resurrection, but no other answers on any websites suggested the above fix, just want to get it out there for anyone else still having the problem.